# How to implement a simple lock mechanism for multi-user application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, multi-user

I really don't want to re-invent the well here, so I'm asking for ideas to implement a simple (row) lock mechanism in a multi-user DB application.

Suppose I have a Table called `Products` which of course has an ID (PK), and also a `rowversion` column (which is not used so far), and I want to allow only *one* user to be able to Edit a specific row.

While this users is editing the record (after a "check in"), other users can only *View* this record (read-only), but not modify or delete it. when the user is done and saved the record ("check out") this record will be again available for editing/deleting by other users.

I have a few ideas (such as adding a "status" column, or maybe create a "lock" table), but there also be considerations if the "locking user" is holding the record for a long time (suppose he went for a weekend and left his computer opened in edit mode). also how to unlock the record if the program crashed/system power down on the client machine...

I was wondering if there is a good and relatively simple pattern for this (which might include SQL-Server features)?

BTW, My client app is Delphi/ADO (not that it's very relevant).

Comment: As soon as you implement locking then (as you already seem to realise) you tend to have to build something to do unlocking under certain circumstances. Most solutions end up as "sorta-locking" where the users are told that locking is happening (and are occasionally prevented from doing things) but behind the scenes it's chaos. Letting users know who else is accessing a record (and letting them pick up the phone or email, or tap the shoulder of the other users), without enforcing any actual locks, will tend to produce a cleaner overall system

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I hear you. unfortunately, it's a client requirement and I can't tell him: "Sorry, Your users will know *who* is "accessing the record" but they will have to send messages by phone/mail/etc outside the app to get this requirement done". Is this what you  are *really* suggesting?

Comment: I'm suggesting that in *most* circumstances, having two users accessing the same record at the same time is an indication that something is going wrong or needs resolving at the *business* level - trying to solve it via *technical* measures at best (in my experience) produces a system that frustrates the users, i.e. "I just want to change this persons address, why should I care that someone in a completely different function is updating their balance?"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, "having two users accessing the same record at the same time is an indication that something is going wrong..." Why do you think so? A user is updating some Product details, another use needs to update the same Product price. They are physically away one from another. Is that an uncommon scenario? So you say that only letting the other users know that a record is being edited is good enough? How can this scenario be resolved in the *business* level?

Comment: Fine, you don't want to believe me. You resolve this issue at the business level in the way I said - you get them to communicate. And  the problem of two people applying separate updates only arises if you're locking at the wrong level - but the wrong level always seems to be picked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution I implemented in an application ....

```
CREATE TABLE RecordLocks(
[RecordId] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
[datetimestamp] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
[PC] [varchar](100) NOT NULL

)
GO
```

`datetimestamp` has a default of `GetDate()` `RecordId` is a `VARCHAR` because of the primary key in the table I am locking (not my choice). Also this table has the obvious indexes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_LockRecord @RecordId VARCHAR(8), @UserName VARCHAR(100), @ComputerName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRAN; 
DELETE FROM RecordLocks WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, datetimestamp, GETDATE()) > 2; 
IF NOT EXISTS (Select * from RecordLocks WHERE RecordId = @RecordId) 
    INSERT INTO RecordLocks (RecordId, username, PC) VALUES (@RecordId, @UserName, @ComputerName); 

Select * from RecordLocks WHERE RecordId = @RecordId; 
COMMIT TRAN;
END
GO
```

First delete and records older than 2 hours (change to suit)

Check there is no record already locking the the one to lock and if not insert the lock.

Select the record with the RecordId we are interested in.

Then in the calling code check to see if the lock has been successful.  If the username and PC coming back from the select matches the data just passed in the lock was successful.  If the username matches but the PC doesn't the same user has the record open on a different machine.  if the username does not match another user already has it open. I display a message to the user if its unsuccessful I.E This record is currently locked by JoeB on workstation XYZ.

When the user saves the record or navigates away just delete the record lock.

Im sure there are other ways but this works well for me.

**Update**

A record will only be inserted if one does not exist.  The following select will return a record.  If the username and/or pc is different to the data you attempt to insert the record is already locked by another user (or same user on a different machine). So one call does all (so to speak).  So if I make a call `Exec usp_LockRecord(1234, 'JoeB', 'Workstation1')` and the record I get back matches that data I have successfully got a lock on that record.  If the username and/or PC I get back is different the record is already locked.  I can then display a message to the user advising the record is locked, make fields read only, disable save buttons and tell them who has a lock on it if I wish.

Comment: How do you *test* that the record is currently locked?

Comment: I mean that in the Grid/Listview I want to have an icon indicating that the record is already locked (if you know what I mean), not just to get this information *when* user *actually* want to implicitly Edit. BTW, "one call does all"! <g>

Comment: @ZigiZ When you make the call to get your grid data make a `left join` to the RecordLock table. Do a `case` on the field from the recordlock table. For `null` value make it 0 else 1.  In your grid 1 shows a locked record. <g>

Answer (score 2):

With a timestamp, you can get away with "cheating". The workflow looks something like this:

1. Read the row (including timestamp) into memory
2. Let the user do some editing, keeping track of old and new values
3. User hits "save"
4. Read the row's timestamp again (in an isolation level that prevents unrepeatable reads)

   1. If the recently read timestamp is the same as the old timestamp, update the row with the user changed values and commit
   2. If the recently read timestamp is different than the old timestamp, you can attempt to "merge" the changes (i.e. if a completely disjoint set of properties changed, the two changes are compatible). If there is any overlap, warn the user and disallow the save

That should do it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, You suggest that the locking will be "transparent"? so users will ALWAYS be allowed to enter Edit mode regardless of other user already editing the record. Am I correct? "in an isolation level that prevents unrepeatable reads". What isolation level should I use and how? now I'm just using `ADO.connection.BeginTrans`, with IsolationLevel `adXactCursorStability`.

Comment: Correct. You're relying on the workflow I mentioned above to make sure that you don't get one user overwriting another user's updates. As for transaction isolation level, the ff technet article has a nice table stating which behaviors are possible in which isolation levels. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx There's no right answer as to which one to choose; it depends on your other requirements.